# How to prevent eviction on specific keys without setting a TTL?

Tags: redis

*Problem:*
I want to set a TTL on a key (to avoid it lasting forever) but I do NOT want to have that specific key to be evicted. 
When I am setting the TTL I know when it will be safe to expire that cache, but it is NOT safe to expire the cache before this time, and eviction presents the risk of having this cache expire to early.

*Context:*
I am using Redis to cache an object in multiple languages, if the underlying data changes however I want to remove all associated caches from Redis.
The way I went around and sorted this problem was to create a SET on Redis that contains a reference to the keys in every language. My concern is that if that SET is evicted - I loose the reference to the other keys, and risk having them persist on the cache when they shouldn't.

*What I am looking for*
A Redis command that looks something like
PLEASE_DO_NOT_EVICT key
while not preventing that key from expiring after the TTL runs out.

Thanks very much for taking your time to reading and answering!

---

While I could use wildcard matching to find all of the associated keys, this is WAY slower than SMEMBERS, and I am doing this in an environment where every MS counts, as these objects are created and deleted very frequently, so this query happens very often.

---

Not having a TTL in these objects means they start building up in memory which is undersirable. And they do tend to stop being referenced after a while

---

Having a no eviction policy seems risky, and I would very much want to

---

When creating:

```
SADD 'object:id:group', 'object:id:spanish'
SETEX 'object:id:spanish', 'Este es el object en espaniol', 100
EXPIRE 'object:id:group', 100
```

When expiring the group because the object changed:

```
SMEMBERS 'object:id:group'
=> 'object:id:spanish', 'object:id:english'
DELETE 'object:id:spanish', 'object:id:english'
DELETE 'object:id:group'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `maxmemory-policy` to its default value of "noeviction". In this mode, no keys are evicted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did state: "Having a no eviction policy seems risky, and I would very much want to"

I've considered this, but going over the memory limit is an expense I'd rather avoid if at all possible!

Comment: Oh, didn't see that statement... what's risky about it?

Comment: The concern is ever growing memory usage if there is a large application usage spike